# Android - ping, Cannot resolve method "findViewById(int)"

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am absolute beginner in Android programming and i have following code:

```
public class First_Fragment extends Fragment {

    View myView;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.first_layout, container, false);
        return myView;


    }



    public boolean executeCommand(){
        System.out.println("executeCommand");
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        try
        {
            Process  mIpAddrProcess = runtime.exec("/system/bin/ping -c 1 8.8.8.8");
            int mExitValue = mIpAddrProcess.waitFor();
            System.out.println(" mExitValue " + mExitValue);
            if(mExitValue==0){
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }

            TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            tv.setText(mExitValue);

        }
        catch (InterruptedException ignore)
        {
            ignore.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println(" Exception:"+ignore);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println(" Exception:"+e);
        }
        return false;


    }

}
```

I have few questions:

1) Why I have error "Cannot resolve method "findViewById(int)"" in part

```
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
```

changing it to "...view.findViewById(..." does not work ("Cannot resolve method "view(int)""

2) Is that right when I want to have that "label" as text output for "ping"

3) How to export only that part with "ping" and if the server have no response (timed out or etc.) it will change text of that label to something else etc "server down")

I will be really happy if you help me with this, I just want to say again, that I am absolute beginner, so please dont blame me. Thank you!

Comment: you need to use `myView.findViewById(R.id.textView2)`

Comment: Ok. So first of all que.1 its can not resolve method `findViewById()` in `executerCommand()` method because it is Fragment and fragment class does not have any `findViewById()` method as Activity. So you have to get it by View, in your case it is `myView` from `onCreateView()`.

Comment: Que 2. as `setText()` only accept `CharacterSequence`  means String or int if you defined your string in resource xml file, you have to convert your mExitValue in String first than set it to Textview like,  `tv.setText(String.valueOf(mExitValue));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 public class First_Fragment extends Fragment {

        View myView;
        TextView tv;
        @Nullable
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.first_layout, container, false);
         tv = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            return myView;


        }



        public boolean executeCommand(){
            System.out.println("executeCommand");
            Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
            try
            {
                Process  mIpAddrProcess = runtime.exec("/system/bin/ping -c 1 8.8.8.8");
                int mExitValue = mIpAddrProcess.waitFor();
                System.out.println(" mExitValue " + mExitValue);
                if(mExitValue==0){
                    return true;
                }else{
                    return false;
                }


                tv.setText(mExitValue);

            }
            catch (InterruptedException ignore)
            {
                ignore.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println(" Exception:"+ignore);
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println(" Exception:"+e);
            }
            return false;


        }

    }
```

In addition fragment needs to define the view whose component it is using. Here myView is the view in which layout is inflated and hence we need to define that fragment is using textview of myView by doing:

```
tv = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
```

Comment: give brief explanation of whats the reason for problem of OP.